# kendo ui set view model page data-title dynamically mvvm

Tags: mvvm, data-binding, kendo-ui

I am trying to set the title of my view dynamically with no success so far.
I am trying something like this:

```
<div data-role="view"
 id="mt-details-view"
 data-title="#= pageTitle #" <---- this one
 data-layout="mt-main-layout"
 data-init="X.details.onInit"
 data-before-show="X.details.beforeShow"
 data-show="X.details.onShow"
 data-model="X.details.viewModel"
 data-use-native-scrolling="true">
```

I tried using a function, tried setting a viewModel variable, tried passing the title from the `view.params`, tried also to set the title on the `onShow` function like that:

```
function onShow(e) {
    X.debug.dbg2(e.view.id, "onShow");
    viewModel.setViewParams(e.view.params);
    e.view.title = e.view.params.pageTitle;
    e.view.options.title = e.view.params.pageTitle;
    fetchSomeDetails();
}
```

nothing works.

Enlighten me please!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one approach you can try. After declaring your viewmodel, bind a function to its 'set' method. Within here, check whether the field being set is the page title property on the viewmodel. If it is, find the dom element holding the title text and set its html to the value being 'set':

```
X.details.viewModel.bind("set", function(e) {
    if (e.field == "pageTitle") {
        $("#mt-details-view [data-role='view-title']").html(e.value);
  }
})
```

Whenever that property is changed on the viewmodel, you will now see it reflected on the page. However there is still the issue of setting the value in the UI initially. You can do this in your onShow function which of course happens after the view is rendered and all the dom elements have been created:

```
function onShow(e) {
    var temp = viewModel.pageTitle;
    viewModel.set("pageTitle", null);
    viewModel.set("pageTitle", temp);
}
```

That will force the 'set' method on the viewmodel to run and the UI should then update.

Comment: Thanks this was very helpful! About the data-title field, is it of any use to set any value to it in the view? I noticed that a variable there like that: `data-title="#= pageTitle #"` won't work, right?

Comment: No value in doing so in this case. The data-title="#= pageTitle #" syntax will only work if within a template, where the value of the pageTitle property will be injected into the generated html but I assume you are not using a template here.